# Changing text file permission on Python

Tags: python, file-permissions

i am trying to lock a certain text file with PERMISSION, and that the program and only the program could access the file & reading & changing it. **even when the program is not wokring!**

I've tried doing this with lockfile method but it locks the file while you are writing to it, and it is not what i need, also tried to change permission with os.chmod but i dont fully understand how it works even tho i looked up. I've tried something like that

```
os.chmod(stat.S_IXUSR | stat.S_IXGRP | stat.S_IXOTH)
```

Comment: POSIX file permissions like this can't restrict access to a single program. The best you can do with these permission types is restrict access to a single user (well, and root).

Comment: Yarin, some of the answers there seem to address your needs exactly.